# How do I get a list of all Content Types in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-type

Is there a simple method for retrieving all of the Content Types available on a Drupal 6 site?  This seems like a simple issue but I can't seem to find a relatively simple way to handle it.

I think I could parse across the database tables for the names but that seems like an overkill query for such a simple need.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a function in the Drupal API that does this for you.  Take a look at [node_get_types()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_get_types/6).

If you do: `<?php $content_types = node_get_types('types'); ?>` all info about content types is returned (name, module, description, etc), or you can do `<?php $content_types = node_get_types('names'); ?>` that gives you a simple array with the machine names as the keys and the human-readable names as the values

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would go to :

```
yoursite/admin/content/types
```

The Schema module could give you an overview of your database structure, you could also look at all the tables prefixed content_type_

Answer (score 0):

If you also want the fields within the content types, you can use this functions.

```
$fields = $fields['content types'][$content_type]['fields'];
```

Check http://www.drupaltonight.com/2012/01/drupal-6-php-snipper-to-get-list-of-all.html for the full snippet.